# How should I design a main role for a user with rollify?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, roles, rolify

For example, a user can be both an `admin` and a `player` and I would like the user to set a main role. For example, I can be a `player` and then switch later on to be an `admin`.

The obvious is to attach a `main_role` with a `role_id` on the `User` model.

However, I'm worried that I'll have to keep the main role in sync with the roles that the user has. For example, if a user is no longer a player, her `main_role` can't be that of a player.

Another way that I was thinking is to order the roles in which the first will be the main role. I can't find an easy way to do that though.

`Ex: user.roles.map(&:name) => ["admin", "player"]`
In this case, the main role is "admin" and I can swap the "player" to be first if I want the main role to be player.

Does anyone have any good suggestions for handling this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you referring to the [Rolify gem](https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify) ? If so I'm a little confused as to the concept of a main role and a secondary role in this context - aren't the roles binary, you either have the role (and the authorizations for that role) or you don't. What is the motivation for differentiating between a main role and a secondary one?

Comment: Well, let's say you have a mobile client and you want to show different view depending on whether the user is admin or not. An example is when someone is working vs using the app by itself, etc.

Comment: I think what I was trying to get at in my question is why the concept of defining a 'main' role. If a user has the role of admin and player ... then surely they have all rights associated with those 2 roles ... how does making one of them a 'main' role benefit your app? Personally I wouldn't bother with the concept of multiple roles .. in this scenario I would go for a user having one of 3 roles ... player, admin, admin-player. An admin-player would simply inherit the rights for both player and admin. But I don't use rolify so I'm probably not qualified to comment.

Comment: Having distinct rights will be problamatic in the future. We want to have admins for certain functions such as tournament A or league B. Then we want to have players and then captains, etc...The concept of current role is that you may have multiple roles for different things but you would want a default view so as not to get overwhelmed by all the options that a super admin have.

Answer (score 0):

I'd better call that "current_role".

Do not afraid to check current role when you change roles list.

If user lost role that is current_role for him then change current_role to next one from his list.

Yes, I recommend having a current_role that references a role_id with foreign key with ON DELETE RESTRICT, ON UPDATE CASCADE in users table.

If you use something other than postgres then use rail's db consistency checks.

Comment: Curren role is a better term. So, you recommend having a current_role that references a role_id?